# Verify semantic integrity of filesystem

Tags: filesystems, ext3

I just started up my linux box to find that one of my filesystem's had errors: I had to login as root to run `fsck` and hit `y` repeatedly. There were a *lot* of errors. So many that I used silly putty and a Rubik's cube to hold down the `y` key (Using the auto-yes options isn't allowed in these kinds of cases). Even with with the `y` key held down, it took a couple of hours for it to finish the check, but when it did the system booted and I am able to access this file system.

So as far as the computer is concerned, the file system in question is fine. But what I'd like to know is whether or not all of my files on it are fine. This particular filesystem has several thousand images on it, and I did a quick sanity check that I can view some of them, but I can't manually check every file to make sure its intact.

Is there some way, either general or specific, that I can verify that none of the files on my filesystem were damaged? The filesystem is ext3.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there some way, either general or specific, that I can verify that none of the files on my filesystem were damaged?

Without copies of the files to refer to, I think this is impossible.  Have you looked in `/lost+found`?  If anything was corrupted into pieces, those pieces will be left there by `fsck`.

I have seen this happen before too, and as far as I can remember the filesystem really did seem okay afterward.  The ultimate cause turned out to be a failing disk -- `e2fsck -c` created a substantial bad blocks list.  If you have had problems where the system becomes unresponsive and the load average soars (because of 'D', [uninterruptible sleep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_sleep#Uninterruptible_sleep) processes with I/O problems that busy loop the kernel), then this is your issue.

I replaced that disk not long afterward but it continued to work for a number of months (and probably still would, if I plugged it in).  You just have to make sure to use `e2fsck -c` -- see `man e2fsck` -- if you reformat, because the unusable blocks will still be there.

If this happens again, use the `-c` switch.

Comment: Actually, there's a ton of stuff in the `lost+found`, I didn't think to look there. Is there anyway to recover stuff from there?

Answer (score 1):

> But what I'd like to know is whether or not all of my files on it are fine.

Ext3 has no functionality for this, but questions like that come up in IT-security as well.  The solution there is to create a list of hash-sums (i.e. practically unforgeable checksums) over the files and its meta-data and compare these stored sums with the actual sums at times where the integrity of the files is (or could be) questionable.  There are host based intrusion detection systems like tripwire and AIDE that do that at a sophisticated level.

As far as I understand you want to guard against operational errors, in which case a heavy weight HIDS is overkill.

For your question it is sufficient to collect, say, SHA-1-sums of the files you're interested in.

> This particular filesystem has several thousand images on it, and I did a quick sanity check that I can view some of them, but I can't manually check every file to make sure its intact.

For instance, if your images are beneath /images, then something like

```
find /images -type f -exec sha1sum {} \; > images.sha1sums
```

will create the check-sums (will take a while), while

```
sha1sum -c images.sha1sums
```

will verify that the actual files are in accord to the stored check-sums.

Comment: That's a really good idea. It doesn't really help me now, but when I get this sorted out, I will definitely do this.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't add a comment. So I am putting it here. Apart from the filesystem test, may be you can also you the Disk Utility to run SMART test on the disk and verify the health of the disk.

Comment: It's a good idea, and I will, but it's an MD array, so I'm not really sure how to interpret the results.